# how can I correctly apply the erase remove idiom on a sorted vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Often, we'd like to apply the [erase remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) to properly eradicate an element from a vector e.g.:

```
v.erase( std::remove( std::begin(v), std::end(v), 5 ), std::end(v) );
```

where v is a vector of integers.

But what if the vector were sorted first? Will the following do the same thing, and if so, is it the most optimal way?

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

IntegerVector::iterator it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 5);

if(it != v.end()) {
    (void)v.erase(it, v.end());
}
```

Does this correctly apply the erase-remove idiom? Is the vector still sorted after the removal process (I assume that it is)? Don't we need to do something like this:

```
(void)v.erase(std::remove(it), v.end());
```

(incorrect syntax for std::remove, but hopefully you get the idea).

Thanks,

Ben.

Comment: Note: You do not have to write `(void)v.erase(...);`; `v.erase(...);` will do the same.

Comment: Dieter, that is true, but erase returns an iterator and for fully lint-free code, its necessary to cast it to void. I like my code to be lint-free

Comment: It looks like you are erasing *all* elements starting from the first occurrence of 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the erase-remove idiom any more but, yes, it'll do the job correctly, optimally and stably.

`std::remove` gathers all the unwanted elements into one contiguous block before erasure, but your sortedness has already done that so it's not needed.

You can drop the meaningless `(void)` prefixes.

Comment: Many thanks Lightness Races in Orbit. (Re casting to void, I prefer my code to be lint-free so any statement that returns something that I don't then require, I cast to void; it's just a personal habbit :-) ).

Answer (score 4):

You may use:

```
auto range = std::equal_range(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 5);
v.erase(range.first, range.second);
```

For C++03, you have to replace `auto` with (the verbose) `std::pair<IntegerVector::iterator, IntegerVector::iterator>`

`std::equal_range` returns a pair of iterator where range `[first, second)` has values equivalent to given value (`5` here) (assuming `v` is sorted).

Comment: Thanks, could you explain with some comments what each line is doing, that would be most helpful. I should also point out, I don't currently have access to a c++11 compiler

Comment: Cheers for the additional commentary

Answer (score 1):

Quite sure your code is not correct, assuming you want to remove all elements equal to 5. 
Here is the corrected version:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

auto lower = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 5);

if(lower != v.end()) {
  auto upper = std::upper_bound(lower,v.end(), 5);
  v.erase(lower,upper);
}
```

Comment: The example I gave was ripped straight from the wiki page :-). In practice, the vector I am using contains a set of non-repeating objects. So it should suffice to just remove the first one (since there is only one of a given value).

Comment: @Bgie: `std::equal_range` does both bounds directly.

Comment: @Jarod42 I know, but then I would be simply copying your (better) solution. I only wanted to provide a minimal change to correct the error.